# Dell's equivalents for HP's hpasmcli and hpacucli tools?

Tags: dell, hp, hardware

As per title. Basically what are Dell's online tools for checking or changing BIOS/RAID-controller level conf. For Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Dell suite is called "Open Manage".
You have a lot of info [here on their site](http://linux.dell.com/wiki/index.php/Repository/OMSA).
Basically on a rpm-based distro ( in my experience this works very well with rhel-based distros) you just have to do:

```
wget -q -O - http://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/latest/bootstrap.cgi | bash
yum install srvadmin-storage
```

( actually dell recommends srvadmin-all, but if you just want to manage your raid controller this is enough ).

Then you have to look at:

```
/etc/init.d/dataeng start        => starts the services need
omreport storage controller=0
  => info about your controller
omreport storage -?    => help for getting info
omconfig storage -?    => help for configuring your card

omreport storage vdisk controller=0  => status of virtual disks
omconfig storage controller action=createvdisk .....  => create an array
```

CAVEAT: on some dell servers ( ie: PE1950 with bnxII nic drivers ), if dataeng starts before then xend service ( if your host is a dom0 xen server ), you will loose network connectivity!!!. If you have the problem take care to configure the dataeng service to start *after* the xend service.

enjoy

edit: with srvadmin-all you will have various tool which will help you to update firmware, manage drac cards and many things. For Temp monitoring and so on you can do this with ipmi, without the dell packages ( you need however to install ipmi tools and drivers ).

Comment: which srvadmin package do I need to install for checking other non-disk controller params/stats/censors? e.g. fan rotation, cpu temperature.

Comment: do you happen to know the answer to the above?

Comment: You'll need the `srvadmin-all` package.

Comment: @ewwhite, after I install srvadmin-all I cannot get hardware info out of omreport commands. does it need a following reboot?

Comment: You need to restart the relevant init services. (or reboot)

Answer (score 1):

The RAID controller stuff is the never-to-be-sufficiently-damned MegaCli; I don't recall off the top of my head what the BIOS management tool is, but I'd be surprised if it wasn't in the smbios toolset somewhere (I've used that tool to get/set the service tag; never had the need to fiddle with BIOS settings directly, though).

Comment: with the smbios toolset you can use getSystemId to retrieve the service tag. But I did not use the MegaCLI since the PE2650 on RHEL3.

Comment: We still use it on our Rx10s/H700s.  What command-line tool do you use?

Comment: currently I use exclusively omreport / omconfig, as they are available since rhel4, if I remember well. On the pe 2600 I remember there was indeed a "megacli" cmd line tool which allowed some configuration of the perc3i card, but I do not remember its name precisely.